# Display port stops working when Intel Virtualization Technology enabled

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtualization, gpu, displayport

I'm running windows 7 64 bit on an Asus Sabertooth z77 motherboard and have a monitor attached to my Asus GTX 870 GPU. In order to create a virtual machine I need to enable "Intel Virtualization Technology", however, when I do this the Display Port on my GPU stops running when windows boots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by first disabling "Fast Startup". Instructions found from [windows website](http://acer--uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/37059/~/windows-10%3A-enable-or-disable-fast-startup):

```
Type Control Panel in the search box.
Click Control Panel.
Click Power Options.
Click Choose what the power buttons do.
Click Change settings that are currently unavailable.
Scroll down to Shutdown settings and uncheck Turn off fast startup.
Click Save changes.
```

Now you need to go into the BIOS menu. (For me I have to hit del at startup and then go into the advanced menu). From here go into the "Advanced" Tab from the top bar and expand "CPU Configuration" option. In here you can enable "Intel Virtualization Technology".

I also had to open the "System Agent Configuration" option in the "Advanced" tab and change the graphics configuration for Primary Monitor to "iGPU"

Hope this helps someone in the future!